# Why do these similar looking statements yield objects of different types?

Tags: scala

In the book 'Scala for the Impatient' the author provides the following two examples for 'for-comprehension':

```
for (c <- "Hello"; i <- 0 to 1) yield (c + i).toChar 
// Yields "HIeflmlmop"

for (i <- 0 to 1; c <- "Hello") yield (c + i).toChar
// Yields Vector('H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'I', 'f', 'm', 'm', 'p')
```

However, he didn't mention why the output is a String in the first case, and Vector in the second. Could someone please explain? Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Your first example is translated into something like:

```
"Hello".flatMap(c => (0 to 1).map(i => (c + i).toChar))
```

and the second to

```
(0 to 1).flatMap(i => "Hello".map(c => (c + i).toChar))
```

`StringOps.flatMap` returns a `String`, so your first example returns a `String` as well. `Range.flatMap` returns an `IndexedSeq` instead.